# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function I need color to be separated from data

Tags: sql

Data:-

```
Seat Post
Steerer
Seat Stays
Seat Tube
Top Tube
Tension Pulley
Rear Derailleur Cage
HL Road Frame - Black, 58
HL Road Frame - Red, 58
Sport-100 Helmet, Red
Sport-100 Helmet, Black
Mountain Bike Socks, M
Mountain Bike Socks, L
Sport-100 Helmet, Blue
```

I tried to separate colour from above data to different column by using below substring function but I received a error can any one help me to get get output

```
select substring(name,charindex('-',name)+1,(charindex(',',name)-charindex('-',name))-1) as colour 
      from [Production].[Product]
```

Comment: Too broad.  Your data varies greatly and you need to tell us the rules for how you want to parse it.

Comment: Please tag your [RDBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms).